# Confused by location of spinning circles on iphone6

Tags: iphone, icloud, data-transfer

I am trying to upload my entire iPhone 6 content to the icloud.  When I fire up my phone there is a spinning circle to the right of the wifi symbol but in the left half of the screen.  When I just turn on the screen but do not unlock it, and it is plugged in to charge, the spinning circle is now in the right half of the screen to the left of the "Battery Charge" and "Bluetooth" symbol.  Is something different being indicated by the slight change in position of the spinning circle?

Answer (score 1):

I see this on my phone when the carrier name on the left is quite long, and icons on the left can get "pushed out" to the right of the time display.